# Next-Auth with firebase Authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js, next-auth

just wanna have my custom credential provider which authenticate the entered username and password with Firebase Authentication on sign in page

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

```
    import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"
import { DB } from "../../../constants/firebase"
import { FirebaseAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter"
import * as firestoreFunctions from "firebase/firestore"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export default NextAuth({
    session: {
        strategy: "database",
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: {
                    label: "Username",
                    type: "text",
                    placeholder: "somebody@gmail.com",
                },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const database = getDatabase()
                console.log(database)

                const user = {
                    id: 1,
                    usename: "j",
                    password: "123456789",
                }
                if (
                    credentials?.username === user.usename &&
                    credentials.password === "123456789"
                ) {
                    return user
                }
                return null
            },
        }),
    ],
    adapter: FirebaseAdapter({
        db: DB,
        ...firestoreFunctions,
    }),
    // pages: {
    //  signIn: "/auth/signin",
    //  signOut: "/auth/signout",
    //  error: "/auth/error", // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    //  verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // (used for check email message)
    //  newUser: "/auth/new-user", // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
    // },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.email = user.email
            }
            return token
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            if (token) {
                session.user!.email = token.email
            }
            return session
        },
        redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
            if (url.startsWith(baseUrl)) return url
            else if (url.startsWith("/"))
                return new URL(url, baseUrl).toString()
            return baseUrl
        },
    },
})
```

firebase.ts

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app"
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics"
import { getFirestore } from "@firebase/firestore"
import { getStorage } from "@firebase/storage"
import getFirebaseObject from "./firebaseConfig"

const app = !getApps.length ? initializeApp(getFirebaseObject()) : getApp()
const DB = getFirestore(app)
const storages = getStorage()
const analytics = getAnalytics(app)

export { app, DB, analytics, storages }
```

as you see

```
const user = {
                id: 1,
                usename: "j",
                password: "123456789",
            }
```

in fact except of these static data wanna search and get right user info from the Firebase
I know there are a some other way of doing this but I like working with next-auth for last change wanna make sure there's a spot of light in this was ;)

Comment: did you followed the getting started instructions on next-auth? This code you provided runs on server side

Answer (score 0):

i found this public repository where the author does something similar to what you want to achieve, which is create a custom token with your database credentials.
May be [this repository](https://github.com/qin-spring-development/spring-of-engivia/blob/9c4fdb29f0db0e9ef1904fe75d64c9c2141faba9/src/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.ts) can help you. It has a few errors, but it gave me a general idea about what to do, as I had a similar case.

```js
try {
    if (user !== null) {
        await customTokenSignIn(user.id, user.email);
        (await getUser(user.id)) ??
        (await createUser(toReqUser(user, account)));
        const data = await getUser(user.id);
        setResUser(user, data as ResUser);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return false;
    }


const customTokenSignIn = async (id: string, email: string) => {
  const hash = toHash(id);
  const customToken = await adminAuth.createCustomToken(hash);

  await auth.signInWithCustomToken(customToken).then((res) => {
    res.user?.updateEmail(email);
  });
  await adminAuth.setCustomUserClaims(hash, { sid: id });

  await createUserToken({ id: id, firebaseUid: hash });
};
```